# Why do i fail to read .csv data properly and how could i write the code just to select specific columns?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

the code reads all csv data files from the same path/folder in which i save this VBA Code in a seperate .xlsm file.

The first file gets formated pretty well so i have 3 clean columns. By starting to read the second file within the path it starts to read all data as .csv

Do You know why?

And how would it be possible just to read specific columns from the files which are not specifically next to each other? Like Column A and Column C for example.

Thank you so much in advance

```
Sub Zusammenfuegen()
Dim strOrdner As String
Dim lngZeile As Long, lngZeileMax As Long
Dim lngZMax As Long, lngZeileFrei As Long
Dim wkbQuelle As Workbook
Dim objLST As ListObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Tabelle4.UsedRange.Clear
'Tabelle4.Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Datum", "Umsatz", "Region")
lngZeileFrei = 1
strOrdner = ThisWorkbook.Path

With Tabelle1
 
 lngZeileMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
 For lngZeile = 2 To lngZeileMax
 
   Workbooks.OpenText strOrdner & "\" & .Cells(lngZeile, 1).Value, Semicolon:=True, local:=True
   Set wkbQuelle = ActiveWorkbook
   .Cells(lngZeile, 2).Value = "eingelesen am " & Now
   
   With wkbQuelle.Worksheets(1)
    
    lngZMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lngZeileFrei = Tabelle4.Cells(Tabelle4.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngZMax, 3)).Copy _
    Destination:=Tabelle4.Cells(lngZeileFrei, 1)
    
   End With
   wkbQuelle.Close savechanges:=False
   
 Next lngZeile

End With

With Tabelle4
 Set objLST = .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
  Source:=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
  xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
 objLST.Name = "MeinListObject"
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a text editor like notepad++ to compare the first and second files for any difference in the  separator character, quoting, line ending etc. Do the csv files come from users with different local settings ?

Comment: @CDP1802 thanks. No the .csv data arise from the same source SAP. The only user who generated all these files was me, so actually there cant be a difference.

Comment: OK, what do you actually mean by "read all data as .csv" , do you mean the whole line is read into one column ? Is the 3rd, 4th , 5th etc files read incorrectly as well as the 2nd ?

Comment: yes its the .csv file but i dont know why

Comment: yes exactly like you described its in one column...every row

Comment: Are the values separated by a semicolon ? You could try adding the DataType parameter to the OpenText line `.Cells(lngZeile, 1).Value, DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, local:=True`

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good and if there is any problem, check if csv is well-formatted.

With regard to specific columns: instead of taking all data

```
'.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngZMax, 3)).Copy _
'Destination:=Tabelle4.Cells(lngZeileFrei, 1)
```

set required range with named columns as below

```
.Range("A2:A" & lngZMax & ",C2:C" & lngZMax & ",D2:D" & lngZMax).Copy _
Destination:=Tabelle4.Cells(lngZeileFrei, 1)
```

For example, if source csv has 4 columns A B C D with 20 rows, where first row and second column B should be skipped out, then VBA function Range should look as

```
Range("A2:A20,C2:D20") or Range("A2:A20,C2:C20,D2:D20")
```

Comment: thanks ! Unfortunately its the csv file...is it possible to rewrite all csv files into .xlsx by code do you know that?

Comment: & thanks for the idea regarding the columns, works perfect ! Thank you so much.

Comment: with regard to "rewrite all csv files into .xlsx by code" - you already open csv as Excel using the workbooks.opentext() method https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext The problem is that if csv is not correct then you cannot properly read it as an Excel. Share both csv if you cannot find the problem.